# Brightcove Embedded Player not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, html5-video, brightcove

I am trying to get a Brightcove embedded video player to work in IE8. It is currently working in all other browsers >IE8.

I retrieved this code from this Brightcove example: http://files.brightcove.com/BCL_MediaAPI_example.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Media API Sample</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- Javascript Media API wrapper from opensource.brightcove.com -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.brightcove.com/bc-mapi.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Media API Sample</h1>
    <!-- Start of Brightcove Player -->
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
    <object id="myExperience" class="BrightcoveExperience">
      <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
      <param name="width" value="480" />
      <param name="height" value="270" />
      <param name="playerID" value="921267190001" />
      <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAAA1oy1bvE~,ALl2ezBj3WG3MLvDx9F9zkV06cNK00ey" />
      <param name="isVid" value="true" />
      <param name="isUI" value="true" />
      <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
      <!-- params for Universal Player API -->
      <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
      <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="BCL.onTemplateReady" />
    </object>
    <script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>
    <!-- End of Brightcove Player -->
<fieldset>
  <legend>Videos</legend>
        <div id="results"></div>
</fieldset><br>
    <!-- This is the script to modify for the exercise -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // BCL Media API search maker -- adapted from JS-MAPI on opensource.brightcove.com
        // namespace to keep all the "global" vars together
        var BCL = {};
        // placeholder - params for API call
        BCL.params = {};
        // Media API read token
        BCMAPI.token = "WDGO_XdKqXVJRVGtrNuGLxCYDNoR-SvA5yUqX2eE6KjgefOxRzQilw..";
        // set the callback for Media API calls
        BCMAPI.callback = "BCL.onSearchResponse";
        // set the filter
        BCL.params.any = "tag:nature";
        BCMAPI.search(BCL.params);
        BCL.onSearchResponse = function(jsonData) {
            var str = "";
            for (var index in jsonData.items) {
                str += "<a onclick=\"BCL.playVideo(" + jsonData.items[index].id + ")\" style=\"cursor:pointer\"><img src=\"" + jsonData.items[index].thumbnailURL + "\"/><br/><small>" + jsonData.items[index].name + "</<small></a><hr/>";
            }
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = str;
        }
        // Player API scripting
        // event listener for the player being ready
        BCL.onTemplateReady = function (event) {
          BCL.player = brightcove.api.getExperience("myExperience");
          // get a reference to the video player
          BCL.videoPlayer = BCL.player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
        }
        // play video function
        BCL.playVideo = function(videoID) {
            BCL.videoPlayer.loadVideoByID(videoID);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be so appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the comment from within the opening and closing . I've seen this prevent IE8 working before. No idea why.

Comment: Just tested your code in IE 8.0.6001 on XP in both compatibility mode and not and it's working fine for me.